# Difference between setLogLevel and setProfilingLevel MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, audit, audit-logging

I have gone through both [setProfilingLevel](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) and [setLogLevel](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/) but unable to understand the difference between both. I am working on building an audit dashboard for my application which would help us identify which user is running what queries. Who deleted and updated records etc. By default, MongoDB was only logging slow queries. Then I set logLevel = 1 using the command db.setLogLevel() and now I can see all of my queries in mongod.log file.

However when my logLevel was 0(default) and setProfilingLevel was 2, I was not able to see all queries despite the fact it say in docs

> 2 The profiler collects data for all operations.

What do they mean by all data?

What is the difference between setLogLevel and setProfilingLevel?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to audit (i.e. be guaranteed to be informed of all operations that are happening), you should probably be using https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/auditing/.

Log level applies to a bunch of things besides queries.

Profiling applies to queries and writes only and, via sampling, allows reducing the amount of logged data while still (hopefully) catching enough useful information.